# Find the boundary of $A$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> let $A =  \{ z \in \mathbb{C} ; z= r e^{it} , \;r \in [0,1],  \; t  \in ( 0, 2\pi)\}$ .  Find the   boundary   of $A$

My attempt : If I draw the picture then it will form a unit circle,  I mean  boundary of $A$ will be the  unit circle.

Is it true ?

Comment: I think the set $A$ doesn't contain the line (radius) $(0,1]$ so, in addition to the circle, this line would need to be added to the boundary.

Comment: You're mixing up disc and circle.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $t\in(0,2\pi)$ makes the disk not having the horizontal ray connecting the origin to the point $(1,0)$

Thus you need to include this ray in your boundary, that is the boundary is the union of the unit circle and the horizontal segment connecting the origin to  the point $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Almost.

**Hint** Pay attention also to the angular variable: is $A$ all of the closed unit disk?

---

**Addendum** The angular variable varies in $(0,2\pi)$, meaning one radius of the disk is not in $A$. The points of that radius (and the origin) are part of the boundary, since they are 'near' to points in $A$ and points not in $A$.

Comment: im not getting  @ Alberto   can  u explain more

Comment: You're mixing up disc and circle. And it's not open.

Comment: You are right. Correcting.

Comment: @jasmine: added a clarification to my hint.